# WordPress: How to order child pages in a select menu?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a select box, which allows you to navigate between parent pages and their children, they are given a specific order, in order to display them in a certain way on the website.

I believe that the line of code that interest you is perhaps this one

`$children = get_pages("title_li=&child_of=" . $parent . "&echo=0");`

The full code is below. You can see that the order of the pages on the site is different than the order of the pages in the select menu, that is because wordpress sorts per `order`, my pages are sorted alphabetically. How to sort them by order, so that what you see on the website matches the select box?

```
<?php

// determine parent of current page

if ($post->post_parent)
    {
    $ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
    $parent = $ancestors[count($ancestors) - 1];
    }
  else
    {
    $parent = $post->ID;
    }

$children = get_pages("title_li=&child_of=" . $parent . "&echo=0");
?>
<div id="info-select-wrap" class="single-france-select">
                        <select id="info-select"class="fr-select" >
                        <?php

if (get_the_ID() == $parent->ID): ?>
                        <option value="<?php
    echo get_the_permalink($parent->ID); ?>" selected>&#xf00c; &#xf29c; <?php
    echo get_the_title($parent->ID); ?></option>
                    <?php
else: ?>
                    <option value="<?php
    echo get_the_permalink($parent); ?>"> &#xf29c; <?php
    echo get_the_title($parent); ?></option>

                            <?php
endif;

foreach($children as $child):
    if (has_children($child))
        {
        if (get_the_ID() == $child->ID)
            { ?>
                                        <option value="<?php
            echo get_the_permalink($child->ID); ?>" selected>&#xf00c; &#xf29c; <?php
            echo get_the_title($child->ID); ?></option>
                                    <?php
            }
          else
            { ?>
                                        <option value="<?php
            echo get_the_permalink($child->ID); ?>">&#xf29c; <?php
            echo get_the_title($child->ID); ?></option>



                                <?php
            }
        }
      else
        {
        if (get_the_ID() == $child->ID)
            { ?>
                                        <option value="<?php
            echo get_the_permalink($child->ID); ?>" selected> &#xf00c; <?php
            echo get_the_title($child->ID); ?></option>
                                    <?php
            }
          else
            { ?>
                                        <option value="<?php
            echo get_the_permalink($child->ID); ?>"> <?php
            echo get_the_title($child->ID); ?></option>



                                <?php
            }
        }

endforeach; ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

I tried

```
$children = get_pages("title_li=&child_of=" . $parent . "&echo=0&orderby='menu_order'&order='ASC'");
```

Didn't solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved by adding `sort_column=menu_order`

```
$children = get_pages("title_li=&child_of=" . $parent . "&echo=0&sort_column=menu_order");
```

Just a quick note, `&echo=0` is useless, you can remove it.